# Git delete past commits from the tree as well as working directory

Tags: git, git-squash

Currently, my git tree looks like this

```
                 master
                   ^
                   |
                Commit 3
                   ^
                   |
                Commit 2
                   ^
                   |
                Commit 1
                   ^
                   |
           remote/origin/master
```

What I want to do is, remove the changes from Commit 2 and 3 like they never existed and then push the changes. There were some uncommitted changes that I stashed (They are mainly config files and makeFiles, so I don't want to have them in the tree). Also, I would like to know what is the best process to follow so that I don't end up messing my working directory like I have done now. Please help

Git-newbie,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rebase` is your friend here. The `rebase` command offers an **interactive** mode in which you can decide on what to do for each commit in a specified commit range.

The probably easiest way would just to `rebase` on top of the remote `master` branch.

```
git rebase -i origin/master master
```

You are telling git to `rebase` the master branch on top of it's remote counterpart. Without the `-i` flag (interactive) this would effictively do nothing.

Now your configured editor should open and you should see something like this:

```
pick abcdefg Commit 1
pick hijklmn Commit 2
pick opqrstu Commit 3
(... maybe more commits)

# Here will be comments which explain what's going on ...
```

Now to drop commits you simply have to delete the corresponding line from the file. So it should look like this:

```
pick abcdefg Commit 1
(... maybe more commits)

# Comments can stay ...
```

Now close the editor and git will `rebase` the commits as specified on top of the `origin/master` branch.

You can read more about interactive rebasing in the [*Changing History* Chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages) from the GitPro book or in the [rebase documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1. I'd go with rebase too. But read the documentation first to understand *what* is happening. Don't treat this as some kind of magic spell to fix your problem.

Comment: For anybody else looking at this answer, you might have to use git stash in order to save the changes you have made on top of the last commit before using git rebase and then git stash pop.